# Finding Update Centre in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I recently downloaded and setup SonarQube using these instructions:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes

I now want to open the Update Centre to install the C++ community plugin. However, I cannot find the Update Centre in the web interface. Can anyone please guide me on how to proceed with this?

There is the screenshot from my administration (Administration>System tab)
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In 6.7 the 'Update Center' was renamed to 'Marketplace' and moved into the top level of the admin menu:

[image]

Comment: Okay. So I guess it was right in my face all along. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> `'Administration' (from top menu bar), ribbon 'system', 'update center'`

[image]

I guess you will need "Administer System" permission in global security.

Note- screenshot is from Version 5.6.6, but it should be similar

Comment: I can not find Update Center in the System tab.

Comment: You can also try `<URL>/updatecenter/` or `<URL>/updatecenter/installed` if not working, then I guess you dont have the permissions

Comment: I have attached screenshot of my Administration>System tab in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Hmm, ok, it looks like you are having permissions, but you have another SonarQube version. I cannot help more in this case.

Comment: I guess you of course checked all the content on these pages, right? :D

Comment: I did. Update Center has been renamed to Marketplace in my system. Thank you for your time.